# How to run `usepackage{times}` while keeping texttt font the same

Tags: fonts, times

I'd like to run `\usepackage{times}` but keep `texttt` font the same (the default CM Typewriter Text). How do I do this?

Comment: Please clarify your overall objective. E.g., is it "just" to use `Times Roman` as the main  text font for your document? If it is, what about the math font: Do you want to keep the default (`Computer Modern`), or would you like to switch to a `Times Roman`-based math font? The `times` package resets the default serif, sans-serif, and monospaced (aka "teletype") fonts to Times Roman, Helvetica, and Courier, respectively. You've mentioned that you don't want to reset the monospaced font, but what about the sans-serif font: Should that be changed, or not, in your preferred document setup?

Comment: I would like to use Times New Roman for everything, except \texttt. For texttt, I want to use whatever the default font is (which I believe is computer modern).

Comment: What about `\textsf`-- do you want to keep the default sans-serif font (Computer Modern Sans Serif), or do you want to switch to Helvetica?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach would be to reset the typewriter font after, with

```
\usepackage{times} % Or tgtermes, newtxtext, etc.

\renewcommand\ttdefault{cmtt}
```

In LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, you could do:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\setmonofont{Latin Modern Mono} % Or NewCMMono, CMU Typewriter Text, etc.
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
% Also set the sans-serif font if desired.
```

Comment: +1. You may want to add that the `\usepackage{times} \renewcommand\ttdefault{cmtt}` approach still ends up setting the default sans-serif font to Helvetica clone -- but without allowing for users to adjust Helvetica's x-height.

Answer (score 10):

The current (2020/03/25) version of the [times](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/times) package consists of just 32 lines of code, three quarters [!] of which are comment lines. The eight non-comment lines are as follows:

```
\ProvidesPackage{times}%
[2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3
(SPQR)
]
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\endinput
```

If all you want to accomplish is to switch the main text ("roman", or "serif") font to a Times Roman clone, you could execute

```
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}
```

in the preamble of your document. If, in adddition, you also wanted to switch your document's main sans-serif font to Helvetica, I would actually *not* recommend you run `\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv}` in your document's preamble, as the x-heights of Times Roman and Helvetica are very different. My recommendation would be to run

```
\usepackage[scaled=0.88]{helvet}
```

instead, in order to bring the x-heights of the two fonts somewhat in line with each other.

---

Actually, though, I would *not really* recommend you pursue the approach outlined above, mainly because it doesn't address the issue of how to set up a math font that's visually compatible with the Times Roman text font. Instead, I suggest you run

```
\usepackage[nott,helvratio=0.88]{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

in your preamble. The `nott` option instructs the package not to switch to a new typewriter font. In addition, if you do *not* want to replace the default sans-serif font with Helvetica, just replace the `helvratio=0.88` option with `nohelv`.

Comment: (SPQR) <- what's the ancient Roman Republic doing in a font package in 2020?

Comment: @user253751 - SPQR are also the initials of the late [Sebastian Patrick Quintus Rahtz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sebastian_Rahtz) ([1955-2016](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb37-2/tb116rahtz-mitt.pdf)). His parents no doubt knew exactly what they were doing when they chose his name. And yes, he was their fifth child.

Comment: here I was thinking the SPQR in 2020 was something to do with Times New Roman.

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for fixing the typo in my answer.